Intuition on the asymmetry in the Kullback-Leibler Divergence
given two probability densities $p,q$ over the real numbers. The Kullback-Leibler Divergence $$D_\mathrm{KL}(p||q) = \int_\mathbb{R} p(x) \log\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right) dx$$ is clearly not symmetric. In order for this expression to be well-defined, we would require (I guess) something like that the support of $p$ must be contained in the support of $q$, so if we want to both expressions to be well-defined, they have to have the same support.
In general the KL-Divergence could be seen as a measure for how similar the distributions $p$ and $q$ are. Here the order probably tells us about the region, in which we have a good approximations, that is, if $D_\mathrm{KL}(p||q)$ is small, then the distributions are close in regions with a high density $p$. Similarly, if $D_\mathrm{KL}(q||p)$ is small, then the same holds for regions with a high density $q$.
If we now want to approximate a "true" $p$ by an estimation $q$, is there some intuition, under which assumptions which order is desirable? Especially if we only can select $q$ from set $Q$ such that $p \notin Q$?
Thanks in advance.

Interesting things here

Based on its applications to machine learning (KL loss), I'd be inclined to say that $q$ is some baseline distribution that we're comparing to (a null hypothesis perhaps), typically a normal, while $p$ is the experimental data. In the same way that statistical tests are asymmetric between the test statistic and the null hypothesis, KL divergence won't be symmetric. To answer your question, $D_{KL}(p||q)$ is an expectation over the true distribution $p$, so it's concerned with the "true" values we'll be getting. Does this give you the intuition you were looking for?
